# How to import python module in a shared folder?

Tags: python, import, directory, shared

I have some python modules in a shared folder on a Windows machine.

The file is \mtl12366150\test\mymodule.py

os.path.exists tells me this path is valid.

I appended to sys.path the folder \mtl12366150\test (and os.path.exists tells me this path is valid).

When I try to import mymodule I get an error saying the module doesn't exist.

Is there a way to import module that are located in shared path?

Comment: I should add some context to my problem :)
Our application offers a few utility scripts to user. We want those script to be in a shared folders so all users can access them easily. 

I tried using forward slashes. It didn't work.
I tried modifying PYTHONPATH. It didn't work.
I am sure the path is correctly escaped. os.path.exists confirms that the path is a valid one. 

I am able to execute file in this folder (or to use open() on them.

My only problem is importing module from this path!

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to use a raw string, or escape the backslashes, in your additional sys.path component? Remember that "\t" is a tab, whereas r"\t" or "\t" are a backslash followed by a tab.

In most applications you are actually better off using forward slashes rather than backslashes even for Windows paths, and most Windows APIs will accept them just fine. Otherwise, be careful to use raw strings!

[There is no need to add __init__.py files in the directories above a simple Python module]

Answer (score 1):

You say os.path.exists() says the path is there, but are you absolutely sure you escaped the \? Try this:

```
sys.path.append('\\mtl12366150\\tes')
```

Comment: If you really want to use backslashes, just use r"\mtl12366150\test".  The better advice is to use forward slashes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

To import a python item there needs to be a `__init__.py` file in each of the folder above it to show that it is a valid python package.

The `__init__.py` files can be empty, they are there just to show structure.

```
\mtl12366150
  __init__.py
  \test
    __init__.py
      \mymodule.py
```

Comment: This is not true. If you do sys.path.append("mtl12366150/test"), those directories do not need to be packages.

Comment: He's importing a single file directly, not a package directory.  __init__ isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As S.Lott said, the best approach is to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable. I don't have a windows box handy, but it would look something like this from your command prompt:

```
c:> SET PYTHONPATH=c:\mtl12366150\test
c:> python
>>> import mymodule
>>>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to append to `PYTHONPATH` rather than overwrite it all?

Comment: @Evan Fosmark: Depends.  80% of the time, it's not used.  Most packages are installed in lib/site-packages.  It's rare, actually, that there's any pre-existing, system-wide PYTHONPATH.  Rather than set a system-wide path, we generally just install the package.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. I was using Python 2.6.1 and with Python 2.6.2 it now works. I had the same faulty behavior with python 2.5.4.

Answer (score -2):

"I appended to sys.path ..."

Please don't.

Set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable from outside your application.

Comment: No, there are perfectly valid reasons to append to sys.path.  Just don't *prepend* the path, since then you'll override any PYTHONPATH set by the user; those should take precedence.  In any case, this is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: "irrelevant to the question" perhaps not.  Perhaps the attempted update to sys.path **is** the problem.